# iOS 9 Universal Links not launching the app from the same domain

Tags: ios, safari, ios9, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I have setup my AASA JSON file to open the app when someone visits `myDomain.com/ShowInTheApp/*`

This works from Notes App, Email, Gmail App, Gmail web on safari and basically any other websites other myDomain.com .

When `myDomain.com/chooseAppORweb.html` contains a link to `myDomain.com/ShowInTheApp/` , safari always opens it in the same tab, app wont get launched. I can tap and hold the link to show the context menu that contains an entry "Open In [My app name]" which will indeed launch my app. But not by single tapping on the link.

When I do the exact same steps from another domain, `NOTmyDomain.com/chooseAppORweb.html` always launches the app without issues.

Has anyone succeeded in launching the app consistently from the same domain using UL ?

Also, if there is an Apple's document that explains any of these behaviours, please share the link.

Comment: Unfortunately while this is not documented, this does seem to be the desired behavior. Once a user is on your website, you can't make attempts to take her into your app.

Comment: You'll note also that users who are taken into your app via Universal Links can choose to open your website -- your website will be shown in the right corner of status bar. My guess is that the team at Apple didn't want to allow developers to continuously take users into the app if the users are trying to stay on the mobile website. It makes sense, even if it has unfortunate side effects like what you're describing.

Comment: @st.derrick Thank you for confirming the behaviour. I saw some posts dating back to June when iOS9 was on beta that some users faced problems when a Universal Link target webpage can never be browsed on Safari because tapping any link would open up the app. I think the Breadcrumb Domain link on the status bar that would set the preference of a website to always open in Safari, the smart banner that reverse this preference and the behaviour mentioned in the question are all Apple's quick fixes to the issues they didn't foresee when designing Universal Links.And that explains why its not in docs

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure when Apple added this to their documentation, but it's explained on their [Support Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) page, in the first note:

> In iOS 9 and later, universal links let users open your app when they tap links to your website within `WKWebView` and `UIWebView` views and Safari pages, in addition to links that result in a call to `openURL:`, such as those that occur in Mail, Messages, and other apps.
>
> When a user is browsing your website in Safari and they tap a universal link to a URL in the same domain as the current webpage, *iOS respects the user’s most likely intent and opens the link in Safari.* If the user taps a universal link to a URL in a different domain, iOS opens the link in your app.
>
> For users who are running versions of iOS earlier than 9.0, tapping a universal link to your website opens the link in Safari.

(Emphasis added)

Essentially, once a user reaches a page hosted on your domain in Safari, any links they follow on your domain will be opened in Safari, even if they're defined as Universal Links by your app.

Comment: I think Apples assumption of "the user’s most likely intent" is just stupid and a nuisance. The developer defines specific paths to act as trigger for universal links. And the developer places links that are supposed to open the app. Who respects the developer here? I know who doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

As st.derrick mentioned above, this is the in-place behavior for Universal links. If you have previously been taken to the App from the link, but then choose to be taken to the website when prompted with a long press, the functionality to open the App will break. You can remedy this by long-pressing again and choosing to open in-app. It's not an ideal solution, but it is the only way I've seen it be fixed. I hope this helps!