# Universal link failing due to "Bad apple-app-site-association server trust"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-universal-links

I am trying to set up a universal link in iOS for my app (still in development, not on the app store). I am running the app directly from XCode onto a iPhone (iOS 11).

My meta data validates fine on https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/

These are the errors I get in the console:

```
Mar 16 12:18:53 iPhone swcd(CoreUtils)[198] <Notice>: ### Bad apple-app-site-association server trust: -6754/0xFFFFE59E kAuthenticationErr, 1 (kSecTrustResultProceed), {
"TrustResultDetails" : 
[
    {},
    {}
],
"TrustResultValue" : 1,
"TrustEvaluationDate" : 2018-03-16 19:18:51.496315,
}
Mar 16 12:18:53 iPhone swcd(CoreUtils)[198] <Notice>: ### Rejecting URL 'https://*REDACTED*/.well-known/apple-app-site-association' for auth method 'NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust': -6754/0xFFFFE59E kAuthenticationErr
```

I have set up the applinks:... entry in Associated Domains in my app.

I found a bunch of people complaining about problems with universal links (on SO and elsewhere), but most of them are getting different error messages, and none of the suggestions helped.

Anyone have any suggestions to further triage this?

(For those wanting to respond, please read all updates first, especially #4)

UPDATE:

SecTrust.h header file seems to indicate value of "1" is not an error:

```
kSecTrustResultProceed  CF_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_3, 2_0) = 1,
...
@constant kSecTrustResultProceed Indicates you may proceed.  This value
may be returned by the SecTrustEvaluate function or stored as part of
the user trust settings.
```

I'm guessing the error is something else not directly related to trust.

UPDATE 2:

Several people said that 'activitycontinuation' was required for this to work, but adding it didn't help. See my association file below:

```
{
    "activitycontinuation": {
        "apps": [
            "*redacted*.*redacted*"
        ]
    },
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "*redacted*.*redacted*",
                "paths": [
                    "*"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

UPDATE 3:

It seems some posts indicate that this error means SSL is not properly set up on the server. However, I can access my site from both desktop and mobile Safari without issue, and there are no certificate errors. I have not added any special certificates as it is using a public root server (Digicert).

UPDATE 4:

When I tried this after the weekend this error disappeared without any changes on server or client. Maybe it was some caching issue.

Nevertheless, the universal link still does not work. Clicking on 'open' from within gmail does open in my app, so it is clear the association is there. However, when I hit a link on that server from within Safari it just goes directly to the server. I can pull down in Safari and see my app on the exposed UI and clicking 'Open' brings up the app. But I am expecting it to automatically redirect from Safari to my app, and that never happens.

I also tried reinstalling, restarting, etc. but no change.

UPDATE 5:

I was able to get the UL working, though it was very finicky about in what situations it will work from.

However it broke again this morning, apparently for no reason, and I am getting "Bad apple-app-site-association server trust" error again.

This really seems like a iOS bug.

I'm going to update to 11.3 and run some more tests.

Comment: To 100% verify it isnt trust related (which I tend to think it is) please write a very simple ios app that makes 1 request against the server to download a random file. dont use any fancy webbview stuff but use NSURLSession. That way you can see if the server really passes Apple's ATS.

Comment: Regarding update 4. I think Safari differentiates between universal links to the same domain and links to a separate domain. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554973/

Comment: Is your device's network communications being proxied through another server? If you are using a corporate device with MDM, sometimes there is a root certificate injected into all network communications.